# How to mock a Unit method in scala

Tags: scala, mocking

I have a method which doesn't return any value actually it process a data frame and registers as temp table, when I try to mock that method for testing I get below error.

```
is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

sample code:

```
val mock_testmethod=mock[objectwrapper](Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
  when mock_testmethod.unitmethod(any[String]).thenReturn(dataframe)
```

I am new with mocking and scala.

Comment: `.thenReturn{()}`

Comment: tried with that it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Actually the error message has given some hints. So you can:

```
doNothing().when(mock_testmethod).unitmethod(any[String])
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped was the following:

```
when(mockedObject.method()).thenReturn(())
```

The empty braces in the `thenReturn` helped me return a Unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
doNothing().when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?